# Pass Parcelable object from an Activity to a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class like this:

```
public class Images implements Parcelable {
    public String[] imageUrls = new String[]{"url1", "url2"};
    public String[] imageThumbUrls = new String[]{"url3", "url4"};
    public Images(){}
    public Images(Parcel in){
        this.imageUrls = (String[]) in.readArray(String.class.getClassLoader());
        this.imageThumbUrls = (String[]) in.readArray(String.class.getClassLoader());
    }
    public int describeContents(){return 0;}
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
        dest.writeStringArray(imageUrls);
        dest.writeStringArray(imageThumbUrls);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Images> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Images>(){
        public Images createFromParcel(Parcel source){return new Images(source);}
        public Images[] newArray(int size){return new Images[size];}
    };
}
```

When I pass it from a FragmentActivity to a Fragment, it is fine. I did it like this:
In the FragmentActivity:

```
MyFragment.newInstance(new Images());
```

In the Fragment:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Images imgs){
    MyFragment mf = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(TAG, imgs);
    mf.setArguments(args);
    return mf;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle s){Images imgs = getArguments().getParcelable(TAG);}
```

But, when I try to pass it from an Activity to a FragmentActivity, it says Unmarshalling unknown type error. I did it like this:
In a click listener of my activity:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent i = new intent(v.getContext(), MyFragmentActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(TAG, new Images());
    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

And in my FragmentActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle s){
    Images imgs = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(TAG);
}
```

I don't know why I can't pass it correctly in second situation while I made it in the first one. Is there anything I missed? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it. I changed the constructor in my Images:
from:

```
public Images(Parcel in) {
    this.imageUrls = (String[]) in.readArray(String.class.getClassLoader());
    this.imageThumbUrls = (String[]) in.readArray(String.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

To:

```
public Images(Parcel in) {
    in.readStringArray(this.imageUrls);
    in.readStringArray(this.imageThumbUrls);
}
```

But I still wonder why it succeeded in the original situation - being passed from MyFragmentActivity to MyFragment.